# Unreal Engine 5.2 Render Movie

Tags: python, video, render, movieclip, unreal-engine5

I have a Sequence file with a metahuman with animations ready to go. How can I render this sequence as an mp4 file using python? Is there any command or flow if commands i can use? Please give examole how to solve.

I cant find anything working on web.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution for rendering your Unreal Engine 5.2 sequence as an MP4 file using Python:

1. Import the necessary Unreal Engine modules into your Python script:

```
import unreal_engine as ue
import os
```

2. Load your Sequence asset from within your Python script using the following command:

```
my_sequence = ue.load_asset("/Game/MySequence")
```

3. Set up your render settings for the sequence, such as resolution and frame rate:

```
settings = ue.MovieSceneCaptureSettings()
settings.set_resolution(1920, 1080)
settings.set_frame_rate(30)
```

4. Define your render output path and file name:

```
output_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "MySequence.mp4")
```

5. Use the following command to render your Sequence as an MP4 file:

```
capture = ue.MovieSceneCapture()
capture.open_output(output_path)
capture.capture_settings = settings
capture.begin_capture()
my_sequence.play()
capture.end_capture()
capture.close_output()
```

Keep in mind that this is just one potential solution, and there may be other ways to do this as well. I hope this helps you out! Let me know if you have any other questions.